# Update Entity Framework Manually

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I use EF in MVC3 projects, for each project I must update EF by NuGet, So I am interesting in update Entity Framework library once time manually rather than per project, how/where can I download and how update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can

1- download dll from [here](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Libraries/EntityFramework.dll)

2- in your project: in solution explorer --> References --> remove "Entity Framework" by right click and select remove

3- right click on 'References' select 'Add reference' in 'Browse' tab select new dll

4- join it.

Comment: the downloaded dll not work correctly, in add references there is an error 'Could not be added'

Comment: also for each project I need to add new library, but I need a way to update once and all new project use this new update